# Calcula con historial en c# usando listas para guardar

Tags: c#

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;


    namespace calculador
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Calculadora....");
     adm dd = new adm();
     bool acep = true;
                List<calculo> hh = null;

               // List<int> he = new List<int>();
                while (acep)
                {
                    string entrada;
                    //Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Elija una opcion");
                    Console.WriteLine("[1] Calcular");
                    Console.WriteLine("[2] Ver historial");
                    entrada = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (entrada == "1")
                    {
    // Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingresa el primer valor");
    calculo cal = new calculo();
                    cal.nume1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    //  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingresa el segundo valor");
                    cal.nume2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    cal.suma = cal.nume1 + cal.nume2;
                    //   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;

                    Console.WriteLine("La suma es: {0} ", cal.suma);

                    dd.hist(cal);

                    Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else  if (entrada == "2")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Historial");

                        hh = dd.verhistorail();
                        foreach (calculo tt in hh)
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Numero 1: {0} ",    tt.nume1);
                            Console.WriteLine("Numero 2: {0} ", tt.nume2);
                            Console.WriteLine("Resultado: {0} ", tt.suma);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        class calculo
        {

            public int nume1 { get; set; }
            public int nume2 { get; set; }
            public int suma;
        }
        class adm
        {
            private List<calculo> he = new List<calculo>();
            public void hist(calculo cal)
            {
                he.Add(cal);
            }

            public List<calculo> verhistorail()
            {
                return he;
            }
        }
    }
```

Trato de hacer una calculadora con historial guardando los resultado en una lista, pero me ha dado un problema cuando guardo el historial, solo me aparece el último resultado en la lista y se borra el anterior.

Si pudieran orientarme mejor sobre que me falta o que otras cosas ademas de lista podría utilizar se los agradeceria.

Comment: Veo varias cosas : 1) bucle infinito, no cambias el valor de acep nunca. 2) Yo cambiaria el `while` por un `do-while` que evalua si acep ha cambiado de valor al final(por ejemplo si has pulsado el "2" y ya no quieres hacer mas calculos) . 3) Tienes el `Console.Clear();`  en el bucle del historial asi que cada vez que hace una vuelta borra el anterior historial,yo pondria al final de la opcion "1" y si el bucle lo quieres hacer infinito al final de la "2" tambien.  Si no te aclaras pongo una respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Asi es con lo del bucle hare una opcion de salir y la variable bool sea false

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Sólo ves el último porque haces un Console.Clear dentro del bucle. Deberías hacerlo antes.

Comment: Gracias me ha funcionado!